# SQL Server multiple table alias precedence > missing column alias

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

Wading through more 'obfuscated' code and refactoring for understanding.  Thought this bit was straight forward till I hit the third case statement.  Can I assume that quoted columns refer to the t_g3 view?

The original FROM portion posted below.

```
FROM  
    [GCCC_ProjectServer_Reporting].dbo.MSP_EpmProject_UserView AS p
INNER JOIN 
    (SELECT 
         t_g3.ProjectUID as ProjectUID
                 ,CASE WHEN @vLastBaseline = 'BL1' AND t_g3.TaskBaseline1StartDate IS NOT NULL THEN t_g3.TaskBaseline1StartDate
                          WHEN @vLastBaseline = 'BL1' AND t_g3.TaskBaseline1StartDate IS NULL THEN t_g3.TaskBaseline5StartDate
                          WHEN @vLastBaseline = 'BL2' AND t_g3.TaskBaseline2StartDate IS NOT NULL THEN t_g3.TaskBaseline2StartDate
                          WHEN @vLastBaseline = 'BL2' AND t_g3.TaskBaseline2StartDate IS NULL THEN t_g3.TaskBaseline5StartDate
                          WHEN @vLastBaseline = 'BL3' AND t_g3.TaskBaseline3StartDate IS NOT NULL THEN t_g3.TaskBaseline3StartDate
                          WHEN @vLastBaseline = 'BL3' AND t_g3.TaskBaseline3StartDate IS NULL THEN t_g3.TaskBaseline5StartDate
                          WHEN @vLastBaseline = 'BL4' AND t_g3.TaskBaseline4StartDate IS NOT NULL THEN t_g3.TaskBaseline4StartDate
                          WHEN @vLastBaseline = 'BL4' AND t_g3.TaskBaseline4StartDate IS NULL THEN t_g3.TaskBaseline5StartDate     
                          ELSE t_g3.TaskBaseline1StartDate          
                 END AS g3_LastBaseline     
                 ,CASE WHEN @vLastBaseline = 'BL1' AND t_cs.TaskBaseline1StartDate IS NOT NULL THEN t_cs.TaskBaseline1StartDate
                          WHEN @vLastBaseline = 'BL1' AND t_cs.TaskBaseline1StartDate IS NULL THEN t_cs.TaskBaseline5StartDate
                          WHEN @vLastBaseline = 'BL2' AND t_cs.TaskBaseline2StartDate IS NOT NULL THEN t_cs.TaskBaseline2StartDate
                          WHEN @vLastBaseline = 'BL2' AND t_cs.TaskBaseline2StartDate IS NULL THEN t_cs.TaskBaseline5StartDate
                          WHEN @vLastBaseline = 'BL3' AND t_cs.TaskBaseline3StartDate IS NOT NULL THEN t_cs.TaskBaseline3StartDate
                          WHEN @vLastBaseline = 'BL3' AND t_cs.TaskBaseline3StartDate IS NULL THEN t_cs.TaskBaseline5StartDate
                          WHEN @vLastBaseline = 'BL4' AND t_cs.TaskBaseline4StartDate IS NOT NULL THEN t_cs.TaskBaseline4StartDate
                          WHEN @vLastBaseline = 'BL4' AND t_cs.TaskBaseline4StartDate IS NULL THEN t_cs.TaskBaseline5StartDate
                          ELSE t_cs.TaskBaseline1StartDate                
                 END AS cs_LastBaseline     
                 ,CASE WHEN @vLastBaseline = 'BL1' AND t_g3.TaskBaseline1StartDate IS NOT NULL THEN 'TaskBaseline1StartDate'
                          WHEN @vLastBaseline = 'BL1' AND t_g3.TaskBaseline1StartDate IS NULL THEN 'TaskBaseline5StartDate'
                          WHEN @vLastBaseline = 'BL2' AND t_g3.TaskBaseline2StartDate IS NOT NULL THEN 'TaskBaseline2StartDate'
                          WHEN @vLastBaseline = 'BL2' AND t_g3.TaskBaseline2StartDate IS NULL THEN 'TaskBaseline5StartDate'
                          WHEN @vLastBaseline = 'BL3' AND t_g3.TaskBaseline3StartDate IS NOT NULL THEN 'TaskBaseline3StartDate'
                          WHEN @vLastBaseline = 'BL3' AND t_g3.TaskBaseline3StartDate IS NULL THEN 'TaskBaseline5StartDate'
                          WHEN @vLastBaseline = 'BL4' AND t_g3.TaskBaseline4StartDate IS NOT NULL THEN 'TaskBaseline4StartDate'
                          WHEN @vLastBaseline = 'BL4' AND t_g3.TaskBaseline4StartDate IS NULL THEN 'TaskBaseline5StartDate'
                          ELSE 't_cs.TaskBaseline1StartDate'        
                 END AS LastBaselineSource
              FROM GCCC_ProjectServer_Reporting.dbo.MSP_EpmTask_UserView AS t_g3
                    LEFT JOIN 
                     GCCC_ProjectServer_Reporting.dbo.MSP_EpmTask_UserView AS t_cs
                    ON t_g3.ProjectUID = t_cs.ProjectUID
                    AND t_cs.TaskIsActive = 1
                    AND t_cs.TaskName = 'Construction Start'
              WHERE t_g3.TaskIsActive = 1
              AND t_g3.TaskName = 'Gate 3 Approval'
              ) as BL
        ON p.ProjectUID = BL.ProjectUID
```

code here

Another example where single quotes are used as column alias wrappers.  Quite common throughout the code base.  This is why I was thinking the above issue was column alias related.

```
SELECT    p0.[Project No], 
    p0.ProjectName,
    isnull(p0.Budg_Centre + ' - ' + p0.Budg_CentreName,' - ') as 'BudgetCentre',
    p0.Budg_Centre,p0.Budg_CentreName,
CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(d,p0.ProjectStartDate,p0.ProjectFinishDate) > 40
                THEN 'Scheduled'
                ELSE 'Unscheduled' END as 'Schedule Status',
            CapFor.Forecasting_Month, 
            CapFor.Forecasting_Year, 
            CapFor.FinancialYr, 
            p0.ProjectOwnerName,
```

Comment: Yes, t_g3 refers to GCCC_ProjectServer_Reporting.dbo.MSP_EpmTask_UserView.

Comment: Cool.  Thanks for the vote of confidence.  Will refactor to t_g3.

Comment: @heuristican, just to be clear, do you mean the names surrounded in single quotes (e.g. `'TaskBaseline1StartDate'`)? Those are character literals, not columns.
'`

Comment: As a rule of thumb - whenever you see multiple columns in the same table, where all you have to distinguish between them is a number, it's probably time to consider normalizing the database.

Comment: @DanGuzman  eg  'TaskBaseline1StartDate'   Throughout columns are referred this way.  While syntactically correct it added to the confusion as you say could be mistaken as string text.  I am refactoring all to [] wrapper format.

Comment: @ZoharPeled  Welcome to my nightmare.  Still cant believe its a sharepoint setup.  Everything is held together with magic numbers (guid).

Comment: @GaryThomann, not just mistaken for string text, those are string text that will be returned instead of the column value. The column names must either not be enclosed at all or enclosed in square brackets or double quotes. Strings in single quotes are literal text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 3rd case is repeating the same logic as the first case but reporting *what column that first case selected* as a string.

Single quotes (`'`) are only ever string literal delimiters<sup>1</sup>.

Double quotes (`"`) may be used as string delimiters or to quote identifiers (in the same way that `[]` can be used to quote identifiers). How they should be interpreted depends on the current setting for [`QUOTED_IDENTIFIER`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/set-quoted-identifier-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017).

So no, do not replace the strings with column references.

---

<sup>1</sup>I'm bound to have forgotten some edge case when I make such a confident assertion, aren't I.

Comment: Oops  getting my quotes mixed up.  Thanks for that.

Comment: Yep, that case is used for testing while it was being built is my guess.  Not referenced anywhere  else so I can comment it out as has no effect.